# When creating a chrome extension, how do you link a javascript page to your popup.html page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a tic tac toe game in the past.  The layout is made using html and when one of the squares in the tic tac toe is clicked, it calls a function in a separate javascript sheet to run the game.  It works perfectly fine so I decided to try to make this game a chrome extension.  However, when I load the extension, the layout shows up fine but when the squares are clicked, then they do not start the game. I think that the page is not loading up the javascript page correctly. Here is the code for the popup.html:

```
      html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<link href="game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<center><u><h1>Single Player Mode</h1></u>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="0"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="1"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="2"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="3"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="4"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="5"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="6"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="7"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="highlight" id="8"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript" src="singleplayer.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The javascript page is separate but it functions fine and is located in the same folder as the html page and the manifest.json.  I just need to figure out why this page cannot load the javascript sheet (called singleplayer.js) in the chrome extension even though it works fine when being run in a browser?  Also one thing that confuses me is that the html page is able to load up the CSS sheet (game.css)when I run it as a chrome extension, so why can it load the css but not the html?

Edit(Function gamestart):

```
var tally=0;


function gamestart(id){
        console.log(id);

    tally=tally+2

    if(tally%1==0){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";
    checkX("X");
    stopbutton("X");    
    setTimeout('player2()',500);
    checktie();
    }
}
```

The function gamestart is simply there to call on other functions which run the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently went through the process of updating one of my extensions from manifest version 1 to version 2, and in doing so I ran into the same issue.  The problem was the inline event handlers conflicting with the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#restrictions).  I was able to remove them from my HTML and then attach them in the script itself.  You might have to modify some of your markup though.  You've got invalid id values on your buttons (id's must start with a letter). Once you fix that, using document.getElementById to get the elements and attaching the click handlers should be a piece of cake.

Edit:

Start by removing the onclick attribute from the HTML. <strike>Do you use the id's for anything?  If you're using them to hold some data value specific to each button, you're better off using a real data attribute:</strike>

```
<button style="background-color:lightblue; color: black" data-val="0"></button>
```

```
<button class="highlight"></button>
```

**Your gamestart function is only using the id to find the button that was clicked.** But there's no need to search the DOM because ***this*** will already be the button that was clicked within the event handler, so just pass it directly to gamestart.

Next, move your script out of the  and put it at the bottom, just before the closing  tag. It's best practice, and you will have access to the elements in the DOM at that point.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="singleplayer.js"></script>
</body>
```

In your script, attach the handlers:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    i,
    n = buttons.length;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
        gamestart(this);
    };
}
```

And modify your gamestart function to take an element instead of an id:

```
function gamestart(el){
    tally += 2;
    el.innerHTML = "X";
    checkX("X");
    stopbutton("X");    
    setTimeout(player2, 500);
    checktie();
}
```

Note also that I changed your setTimeout call.  It's better to pass a function (in this case, player2) rather than a string which then has to be interpreted as a function (as in "player2()").
I think that should do the trick.

Comment: So I should change the id values from numbers to letters?

Comment: Yes, or at least begin the value with a letter.  Could prefix them all with "b" as in "b1", "b2", "b3", etc., if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to attach the inline event handlers to the script?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes it would be nice if you could give me an example of how to attach the inline event handlers.  Should I show you the javascript function that needs to be called?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example.

Comment: It did not quite work, but I think that if you saw the function that needs to be started you could probably figure it out.  I have edited my question and posted the function above.

Comment: Also as a note, I have also changed the html: I have removed the style from the html page and put it into a separate css page.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out a different way.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the restrictions of [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#restrictions), inline event handlers in HTML are not allowed. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution for more information and how to change it to comply with CSP.

Also, could you open the Developer Tools for popup.html and see if there's any other error message in the Console?

Comment: I saw that there was an error in loading the javascript page but I could not figure out what it meant. Thanks!